# Order list of rasters R

Tags: raster, r, order

I have some raster files which names are Band_2..., Band_3... etc. I want to order them from the minimum number (2) to the maximum (12). Here is the code I am using

```
S2_masked<-"/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22"
S2_masked<- list.files(S2_masked, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".tif$")
split <- strsplit(S2_masked, "Band_") 
split <- as.numeric(sapply(split, function(x) x <- sub(".tif", "", x[2])))
S2_masked <- S2_masked[order(split)]
S2_masked<-lapply(1:length(S2_masked), function (x) {raster(S2_masked[x])})
```

I am re-using this code from another project and it used to work but now the output of:

```
split <- as.numeric(sapply(split, function(x) x <- sub(".tif", "", x[2])))
```

is

```
> split
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Any idea?

EDIT -----

So here are the output of S2_masked (line 2) and split (line 3)

```
> S2_masked
 [1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_11_2016_04_22.tif"
 [2] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_12_2016_04_22.tif"
 [3] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_2_2016_04_22.tif" 
 [4] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_3_2016_04_22.tif" 
 [5] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_4_2016_04_22.tif" 
 [6] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_5_2016_04_22.tif" 
 [7] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_6_2016_04_22.tif" 
 [8] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_7_2016_04_22.tif" 
 [9] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_8_2016_04_22.tif" 
[10] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/Band_8A_2016_04_22.tif"


> split
[[1]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "11_2016_04_22.tif"                                                   

[[2]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "12_2016_04_22.tif"                                                   

[[3]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "2_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[4]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "3_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[5]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "4_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[6]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "5_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[7]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "6_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[8]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "7_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[9]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "8_2016_04_22.tif"                                                    

[[10]]
[1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4_S2_image/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22/"
[2] "8A_2016_04_22.tif"
```

EDIT 2 ----

Just found the solution, in case it helps someone else:

Following the advice of @spacedman, I manage to get the number after ¨Band_¨in a different way. This is the number I want to use as reference to order my data so,

In line 3 of the code, instead of using ¨Band_¨as element to split the data, I selected ¨_¨.

```
[[9]]
 [1] "/Users/Miguel/Documents/Paper/4" "S2"                             
 [3] "image/2"                         "1"                              
 [5] "R"                               "Processed/2016"                 
 [7] "04"                              "22/Band"                        
 [9] "8"                               "2016"                                 
[11] "04"                              "22.tif"
```

In that way I end up isolating the number. Then in line 4, I use [9] instead of the previous [2].

After that, the code works and import the data the way I want

Comment: Can you show us the actual names of the files you are trying to read? Perhaps list the contents of that folder? Does your `S2_masked` look okay? Does the first `split` (line 3) look okay?

Comment: If I make a bunch of files called `Band_2.tif` to `Band_12.tif` in a folder then your code works as expected, so it must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: I just edited the question to show you the output of my intermediate steps. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a note - it is not advisable to give variables names of existing functions, in this case `split`.

Comment: @janina you are completely right, did not realise about that.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the sub function (line 4), From the help, it is explained that:

If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning. If NA, all elements in the result corresponding to matches will be set to NA.

Comment: Rather than adding an answer as an edit, I would recommend adding your solution as an answer and then accept Spacedman's answer by selecting the green check next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bit of time to look at your question. Here is a somewhat cleaner solution.

```
library(raster)

S2_masked <- "/2_1_R_Processed/2016_04_22"
S2_masked <- list.files(S2_masked, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".tif$")
bands <- as.numeric(sapply(S2_masked, function(x) x <- gsub("(Band_)(.*?)(_.*)", "\\2", basename(x))))
S2_masked <- S2_masked[order(bands)]
S2_masked<-lapply(1:length(S2_masked), function (x) {raster(S2_masked[x])})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the result of `sapply` you'll see its getting all the part of the name with what looks like the date as well (I made two sample files):

```
> sapply(split, function(x) x <- sub(".tif", "", x[2]))
[1] "1_2016_14_22" "6_2016_04_22"
```

which goes to NA when converted to numeric:

```
> as.numeric(sapply(split, function(x) x <- sub(".tif", "", x[2])))
[1] NA NA
```

because the code is stripping off everything before `Band_` and everything after `.tif`.

You need a different way of getting the number after `Band_`, suspect the solution is to use `regexec`. (No time now for me to do this).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I understand the problem, I am not sure how to use regexec to solve it

Comment: @GCGM You can try this on the full name: `gsub("(Band_)(.*?)(_.*)", "\\2", x[2])` But (!) the raster with the name "Band_8A_2016_04_22.tif" will cause the same problem once again since there is a non-numeric character.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and suggestions. I manage to solve the issue. I edited the question again to add the solution for future readers

Comment: @Janina, you are right the 8A raster cause a problem but it is sent to the final position of the list, which is fine for my purpose.